# jquery ajax call aborts

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout

I need to make some ajax calls to a php script that will process the data and display the results.

But the calls seem to be timing out. in Chrome and Firefox when i check the calls they show up in red.

my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/toimport",
    data: ({"filename": $("#file").val(), "search_engine": $("#engine").val(), "matchtype": $("#matchtype").val(), "year" : $("#year").val(), "country" : country, "sheet" : i, "filetype": file_type}),
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $("#message").append(data);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        $("#message").append(textStatus + '<br />');
    }
});
```

when I make the PHP code trivial (return one of the received values), all the calls are successful, it is only when the PHP takes some time that the ajax call fails.

I tried using timeout on the ajax call, but it doesn't seem to work. The textStatus returned is 'error', errorThrown is empty.

thanks

Comment: check the response header to see what the server is returning (i.e. firebug) as error code. maybe there is an 500 internal server error raised by your complete php script. Most times the server responses truly with an error.

Comment: I get no response headers for those calls that fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle your AJAX call this way:

```
var ajaxCall = $.ajax(options);
```

You can abort your call if you have the reference to your AJAX call:

```
ajaxCall.abort();
```

You need to make extra validations to know if your AJAX call has been done or still working to avoid any error on your `abort` request.

Comment: how do i make the validations?

Comment: every ajax call has properties like 'readyState', this could be '1', '4' and so on. Therefore you need to know when you abort an ajax call that this is not finished because this could throw and exception.